# SMS text message from send-mail.php to 4G percent sign changes to upside down question mark

Tags: php, character-encoding, sms, special-characters, lte

When I send an SMS text message from send-mail.php to a 4G phone the percent sign changes to an upside down question mark. It works fine sending to a 3G phone. The message is about probability of rainfall, for example "10% chance of rain".

```
<?php 
   // Phone number to send to 
   $phone2send2 = '1231234567@vtext.com'; 
   $headers = "From:" . $from; 
   $strForecast = "10% chance of rain"; 
   $body = $strForecast; 
   if (mail($phone2send2, $subject, $strForecast, $headers, "-f me@me.com")) { } else { }        
?>
```

Comment: Do you encode your message at all? Please provide the code that processes the data.

Comment: The the php script is: 
`code`<?php
// Phone number to send to
$phone2send2 = '1231234567@vtext.com';
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$strForecast = "10% chance of rain";
$body = $strForecast;
if (mail($phone2send2, $subject, $strForecast, $headers, "-f me@me.com")) {
} else {
}
?>
`code`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your phone is attempting to parse the string as UTF-8. Somewhere, the encoding is getting confused. Try using the [utf8_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) method:

```
$strForecast = utf8_encode("10% chance of rain");
```

Comment: Thanks!   I wasn't sure how to specify the encoding, your string is very helpful.  I will run some tests and reply when I find out if this is working.  I might take a few days to contact the person with the problem receiving the message correctly on his phone, but I will reply back with results.  Is utf8 best, or should I use ascii?